# set cookie cross origin

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

There are two domain: `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`. The server of `domain1.com`:

```
app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.redirect('domain2.com/');
})
```

and the server of `domain2.com`:

```
app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.cookie("name",'luoxia');
    res.end();
})
```

I found that the cookie is set to `domain1.com`, why?

I want to set the cookie to `domain2.com`. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Setting cookies for another domain are not possible. Allowing this would present an enormous security flaw.
There's no such thing as cross-domain cookies. You could share a cookie between foo.example.com and bar.example.com but never between example.com and example2.com and that's for security reasons.

If you want to pass data to another domain, you can encode this into the URL. or you could so a hack like this.

centralize all cookies in a single domain,

```
   1. let's say cookiemaker.com When the user makes a request to example.com you redirect him to cookiemaker.com
   2.cookiemaker.com redirects him back to example.com with the information you need
```

Of course, it's not completely secure, and you have to create some kind of internal protocol between your apps to do that.

Lastly, it would be very annoying for the user if you do something like that on every request, but not if it's just the first.

see [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3):

> The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute
> specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin server.
> For example, the user agent will accept a cookie with a Domain
> attribute of "example.com" or of "foo.example.com" from
> foo.example.com, but the user agent will not accept a cookie with a
> Domain attribute of "bar.example.com" or of "baz.foo.example.com".
>
> NOTE: For security reasons, many user agents are configured to reject
> Domain attributes that correspond to "public suffixes". For example,
> some user agents will reject Domain attributes of "com" or "co.uk".
> (See Section 5.3 for more information.)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I think you midunderstood my question, as you said, when `example.com` is redirect to `cookiemaker.com`, and the `cookiemaker.com` can't set cookie to `example.com`, but I found that the cookie is set to `example.com` just like my question. I don't want to set the cookie to `example.com` but to `cookiemaker.com`